# In a Baire space $X$, if an open set meets a nonmeager set, is the intersection nonmeager?

Tags: general-topology, baire-category

In a Baire space $X$, if an open set $U$ meets a nonmeager set $N$, is the intersection nonmeager?

If they do not meet then it's false; take the upper half line of the reals. It does not meet some of the open sets below $0$.

Comment: There are some other trivial cases, e.g. $N=\{-1\}\cup\mathbf{R}^+$ and $U=(-1.1,-.9)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. The nonmeagerness of the nonmeager set may happen somehwere away from where it meets the open set (which might be even just a single point).